# Convert Uploaded Files To .pdf

Tags: 7, files

I'm reviewing a spec. that calls for all files uploaded via a file field to be automatically converted to PDF format.  I have two questions:

1. Is this wise?  Files would be uploaded by anonymous customers.  Allowed file extensions (.doc, .xls, .png, .jpg, etc) would be provided as per normal file field use.

(Edited to clarify my main concern is security)

1. Are there any conversion tools you would recommend?  Paid or free is fine.  Remote service is fine, local server-based is preferable.  I can't find anything in the Drupal-verse, but have uncovered tools such as `unoconv` and `JODConverter` that look promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would store the file as it was uploaded, and then render it as a PDF for users when they download it.  Your spec may say PDF *now*, but you want to have the flexibility should things change *in the future*.

Is this a good idea?  That is a tough question, and really depends on the exact scenario.  Personally, I would push back on this requirement.  Format conversion can tax system resources, and I don't think you can really constrain the .doc and .xls formats enough, like you can with images, to be something reasonable.

Tools?  The [Printer, email and PDF versions](http://drupal.org/project/print) module has a list of of the PHP-based PDF modules:

- [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)
- [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/)
- [TCPDF](http://tcpdf.sourceforge.net/)
- [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

I am unaware if any of these will support .doc or .xls formats.  I have used [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to convert images to PDF, and I am pretty sure it has some support for .doc.  I am unaware of any Drupal-ready solution for this, though.

As for security implications, the scenario "makes my spidey sense tingle", but I can't point to anything in particular.  I don't think you would have any problems with any of the malicious payloads in .doc and .xls files that normally affect Windows machines.  However, if you go with a solution like GS, you will have to use a `popen()` or something similar, so you run the risk of an exploit there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback MPD.  My main concern re: this being a good idea is around security.  These are anonymously uploaded files.  Performance is less important.

Answer (score 1):

See if https://github.com/delphian/drupal-convert-file/wiki fits your needs. It will make a backup of the original file, and uses remote providers (currently google drive) to do the actual file conversion. The google drive provider will convert .doc .xls and .txt to .pdf.

Comment: Have you tried the github project yourself? Why is it not a drupal.org project, is it stable enough>